# How can I prove convexity of a constraint set in MATLAB?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

How can I prove convexity of this set in MATLAB or PYTHON?

$$\{(y_1,y_2)\in\Bbb R^2\,\mid\,\forall (x_1,x_2)\in\Bbb R^2, 2x_1^4+x_2^4+y_1x_1x_2^3+y_2x_1^3x_2>0\}$$

Is there any pre-defined library in MATLAB or PYTHON which we can define a set in it?

Comment: Why do you want to prove convexity via Matlab? It can be done pretty easily by hand.

Comment: When an actual formal proof is out of reach, Google comes up with links like this: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/102169-identify-convex-and-concave-parts-of-polygon

Comment: It is very dubious that there is specialized software for this kind of issue (in Matlab for example). Have you worked on this issue ? If yes, where are stumped ? Have you attempted to understand the issue using graphical representations ?

Comment: Please replace in your definition $>$ by $\ge$ (think to the case $x_1=x_2=0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple "done by hand" proof. For fixed $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2$, the set
$$
C_{x_1,x_2} := \{(y_1, y_2) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid 2x_1^4 + x_2^4 + x_1x_2^3y_1 + x_1^3x_2 y_2 > 0\}
$$
is convex, since it is just the solution set of a linear inequality.
The set in question is
$$
\bigcap_{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb R^2} C_{x_1,x_2}.
$$
Thus, it is convex since it can be written as an intersection of convex sets.

Comment: [+1] Indeed, it is almost evident. It is worth mentionning that $C_{x_1,x_2}$ is plainly a half plane, and that the final intersection may be the void set.